# How to consistently center an element across Chrome and iPhone platforms, using CSS?

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome, height

I am really confused right now and can't find anything about it:

this code - quite simply - centers a letter in a circle. The problem: in **Chrome**, the letter is centered, but on **iPhone**, regardless of whether it's an older or newer model, the letter is *no longer centered, but about 7% lower*, so it's no longer in the middle of the circle.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can center the letter (class= "kreiszahl") so that it remains that way in the frontend, even on **Apple smartphones**.

```
span.kreiskritik {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, FARBE1, FARBE2);
    font-family: Lora;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    shape-outside: circle(50%)
}

span.kreiskritik .kreiszahl {
    position: absolute;
    color: FARBE_KREISZAHL;
    top: 52%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 54px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after testing just about everything (and not finding success with line-height nor any of the other tips), here's my solution ☺, which **satisfies me 99%** **because the deviations between Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and iOS, and between desktop and smartphones, are now minimal**:

```
.kreiskritik {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, FARBE1, FARBE2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: FARBE_KREISZAHL;
  font-size: 45px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```